# ArrayController model records are hanging around between calls

Tags: ember.js

I have a search screen with search filters and a results screen with the table of search results.

```
this.resource('search', function() {
    this.route('results');
});
```

When the user selects the submit button on the "search" route they are transitioned to "search.results" route.

When the user changes any of the filters while in the "search.results" route they are redirected to the "search" resource because the results are no longer valid.

The issue I had was that the previous ArrayController records were hanging around between searches.  I had to manually clear the items in the array controller as below so that the old records would disappear.

Why do I need to do this.  Is there a better way around it?

```
model : function() {
    this.controllerFor('search/results').set('content', []); //why do I need this?
    return this.fetchItems(1);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers' content hangs around as you navigate within the app unless something changes them. To clear them, you could use
`this.controllerFor('search/results').get('content').clear()`. If you would rather not clear them and want to indicate that the results are being fetched in some way, like a loading spinner, look at ember's `loading routes`.